# Show that $\left. \frac{d}{dp}\right|_{p=1} \left[ \int f^p \, d\mu \right]^{1/p} =\int f \log(f) \, d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

The following is supposed to draw a connection between Lp norm and entropy: f is a **probability density** below:

$$\left. \frac{d}{dp}\right|_{p=1} \left[\int f^p \,d\mu\right]^{1/p} =\int f \log(f) \,d\mu$$

My derivation always reveals the LHS to be 0. What I did wrong?

$$\frac{d}{dp} \left[ \int f^p d\mu\right]^{1/p} = \left(\int f^p \, d\mu\right)^{1/p} \log \left(\int f^p \, d\mu\right) \cdot  \left(-p^{-2} \right) \cdot \int f^p \log(f) \, d\mu$$

which is $0$ when $p=1$ (since $\log\left(\int f^p \, d\mu\right)=\log1=0$).

Comment: I suspect that it should have $+\int f^p log(f)d\mu$ not $\cdot \int f^p log(f)d\mu$ in the derivative expression.

Comment: Check your application of leibniz integral rule

Comment: Isn't this just chain rule? I don't see why it is plus not multiplication.

Comment: I looked at Leibniz integral rule. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: I was being stupid but the advice above doesn't make much sense either.

Answer (score 1):

Write $h(p)=\int f^pd\mu$. $h'(p)=\int f^p\log(f)d\mu.$

Then we have
$$\frac{d}{dp}(h(p)^{1/p})=\frac{d}{dp}(e^{\frac{\log(h(p))}{p}})=e^{\frac{\log(h(p))}{p}} \frac{\frac{p}{h(p)}h'(p)-\log(h(p))}{p^2}$$

When p=1, the above evaluates to
$$h'(1)=\int f^p \log(f)d\mu.$$